# How to remove Error "Trying to get property of non-object"?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP. I face an error message when i run my code `Trying to get property of non-object` I try all possible solutions provided on `stackoverflow` but i failed. Please have a look on my code and suggest me my error please.

**Please dont mark as duplicate**

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "pacra-daily";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    //$id2 = $_GET['id'];

    $sql="SELECT pacra_teams.title as 'teamTitle', og_users.display_name, og_users.id
    FROM og_users
    LEFT JOIN pacra_teams
    ON pacra_teams.id = og_users.team_id
    Where og_users.id = 106";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_object();
    // setting variable values during session

    echo $row->display_name; // Change to correct column name in table og_users
    echo $row->teamTitle; 
    ?>
```

I got error on

```
echo $row->display_name; // Change to correct column name in table og_users
        echo $row->teamTitle;
```

Comment: In which line of code, you are getting the error?

Comment: @Gunaseelan i got error on `echo $row->display_name; // Change to correct column name in table og_users
        echo $row->teamTitle; `

Comment: check if $conn is an object and $result

Comment: @donald123 can u please explain it for me. I m very thankful to you

Comment: Create a while loop like below. `while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {echo $row->display_name;  echo $row->teamTitle;}` Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: @Gunaseelan it returns empty result set

Comment: @sunny Just execute the sql query that you written to your phpmyadmin and check whether any result is coming or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If query return you empty result set still you are trying to access the row. Access the db columns in a while loop shown as below.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      echo $row->teamTitle;
}
```

Comment: It returns an empty result

Comment: Try to execute your query directly into database and see whether its give you empty result or not? If yes then modify your query..

Comment: Nope sAch your answer is still correct even if there is an empty result.

Comment: Yes @Hanky웃Panky. I just gave suggestion to correct his query.

Answer (score 1):

To check your task ... take a look at php.net http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php

Here is a example for you

```
   <?php
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "";
       $dbname = "pacra-daily";

       $sql="SELECT pacra_teams.title as 'teamTitle', og_users.display_name,                    og_users.id
            FROM og_users
            LEFT JOIN pacra_teams
            ON pacra_teams.id = og_users.team_id
            Where og_users.id = 106";
       $mysqli = new mysqli($servername , $username, $password, $dbname);

       /* check connection */
       if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
           printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
           exit();
       }


       /* Select queries return a resultset */
       if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

                /* free result set */
                $result->close();
      }

      /* If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
      if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

      /* Note, that we can't execute any functions which interact with the
         server until result set was closed. All calls will return an
         'out of sync' error */
      if (!$mysqli->query("SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
          printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
      }
      $result->close();
     }

     $mysqli->close();
 ?>
```